# Taking working experience months from begin end working dates MVC

Tags: linq, model-view-controller

I have a table of people and their work experiences. Each person can have many experiences. I want to get only those people from this table whose experience month sum  in the Specific filter.Position_ID more than the value I provide .

Experience has begindate and enddate also the jobtitle.

Code:

```
result = result
    .Where(w => w.CommonFields.Status == RecordStatusType.Active 
             &&  w.Experiences.Sum(sum => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("month", sum.BeginDate, sum.EndDate ?? DateTime.Now)) 
                 >= filter.WorkExperiency 
             && filter.Position_ID.Any(p => p.Equals(w.Experiences.Where(x => p.Equals(x.Position_ID)))));
```

filter.Position_ID is the positions i provide .
result is all the applicants.
Problem is equal . it doesnt work...  filter.Position_ID is list i want to find if any of those elements == the ones the applicant has in experience.

Comment: So you already have what you want? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = result
    .Where(w => w.CommonFields.Status == RecordStatusType.Active
             && filter.Position_ID.Any(p => w.Experiences.Any(e => e.Position_ID == p))
             &&  w.Experiences.Sum(sum => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("month", sum.BeginDate, sum.EndDate ?? DateTime.Now)) 
                 >= filter.WorkExperiency);
```

this fixed my problem.